# If a system is placed in a gravitational field, can you define internal energy for it?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, gravity, potential-energy

My textbook says that internal energy for a system can only be defined if the system is isolated i.e. it has no external $K.E.$ and is not present in any external force field. But why? Why is it important for the system to be isolated? Is this statement even true? Why can't we define internal energy for a system which is, say, present in an external field or, say, has an external $K.E.$? Why?

Answer (score 1):

The answer really depends on the context.

- In many cases the internal energy is defined as the energy of the interaction between the parts of the system. In this case it is easily separable from the kinetic energy and the energy due to the external force fields.
- However, in the context of statistical physics, the internal energy usually includes the kinetic energy of the parts of the system. To define this energy correctly one needs to calculate these kinetic energies with respect to the center-of-mass of the system, i.e., excluding the energy associated with its displacement and rotation as a whole. External potential still does not pose any problem - but, as it should be clear, it is not a part of the internal energy.

Answer (score 1):

> My textbook says that internal energy for a system can only be defined
> if the system is isolated i.e. it has no external $K.E.$ and is not
> present in any external force field. But why?

It is because it is the *internal energy*, $U$ of the system. The internal energy is defined as the sum of the kinetic and potential energies of the atoms and molecules of the system, i.e., kinetic and potential energy at the microscopic level.

But the total energy $E$ of the system is the sum of its internal energy and its energy with respect to an external (to the system) frame of reference. It is the more general version of the first law. This is the gravitational and kinetic energy of the system as a whole due to its velocity and position with respect to an external frame of reference.

The drawing below may be of help.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: You write $W_{ext} = ΔP + ΔK$ in order to take into account also non-conservative forces? Otherwise $W_{ext}$ will be always zero.

Comment: @AntoniosSarikas Yes, the $\Delta K$ term takes into account non-conservative force. The $\Delta P$ term always, by definition, involves only conservative forces.

Answer (score 0):

Internal energy is defined as an intrinsic physical property of the material (or materials) comprising the system, so it can't depend on how fast the system is moving relative to some frame of reference or its location relative to some gravitational body.  The total energy of a system E can be defined as its internal energy U plus the organized kinetic energy KE and the gravitational potential energy PE:  $$E=U+KE+PE$$Then, the more general form of the first law of thermodynamics for a closed system would read:  $$\Delta E=Q-W$$